# How to create subprojects in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have TFS 2013 and I want to create subprojects for every platform that my app supports. So I would like to have a big project called "MyApp" and  subprojects named "MyApp.Android", "MyApp.WindowsPhone", etc. Each subproject will have it's own git repository and backlog. Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TFS there is no sub-project feature, but the panorama is not completely gloomy.

Since TFS 2012 you have this concept of Team that naturally organize backlog per-Team. For a very visual summary see [Agile Portfolio Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/portfolio-management), while detailed documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/manage-team-assets).
You may also create multiple Git repos for the same TFS Project, but consider carefully the pros and cons.